# How to update website preserving database

Tags: sql-server, web-services

I am working on a web service that uses a database. If I update the code for my website then I have this error when trying to access the database:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "myDatabase" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'MyNameWin\theUserName'.
```

What puzzles me is that the user is the same that created the database. If I delete the database using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio a new one is created and can be used from that point on. While this is not a problem right now, in the future I would like to be able to update my website preserving the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How could we know what you are doing wrong? We don't even know what you are doing.

Comment: That's a valid point. I have so little experience with this, it is hard for me to judge what information is relevant. As I tried to explain, I am publishing a new version of the website, so I delete all files and create the new website version. Then SQL complains abouit the access, but it is fine to delete the database as well and create a new one... (is there anything I could show or explain that would help?)